# Three js Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined at ShaderPass.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to get a basic GlitchPass to work in a Three js demo, but I can't get past `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined at ShaderPass.js`.

For this demo I'm not using files from the `jsm` directory...just the ones from `js`. These are the files I'm including.

```
<script src="~/lib/three/CopyShader.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/three/ShaderPass.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/three/EffectComposer.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/three/RenderPass.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/three/GlitchPass.js"></script>
```

I've included `CopyShader` and `ShaderPass` because without them the EffectComposer throws `"THREE.EffectComposer relies on THREE.CopyShader"` and `"THREE.EffectComposer relies on THREE.ShaderPass"`.

```
<script>
    const hologram = document.querySelector('.hologram');
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, innerWidth / innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 100);
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        antialias: true,
        alpha: true
    });
    renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
    hologram.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    const shader = new THREE.ShaderPass(THREE.CopyShader);
    const composer = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer);
    const renderPass = new THREE.RenderPass(scene, camera);
    composer.addPass(renderPass);

    const glitchPass = new GlitchPass();
    composer.addPass(glitchPass);

    // rendering things here 

    function animate() {
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        composer.render();
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

    animate();

</script>
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of imports. `Pass` is defined in `EffectComposer`.

```js
<script src="~/lib/three/EffectComposer.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/three/ShaderPass.js"></script>
```

BTW: This is a good example for one advantages of using ES6 modules. Compared to global scripts, such dependencies are automatically managed by the module system.

Comment: Still doesn't work using native js (r.125) even when moving ShaderPass after the EffectComposer, but I switched to using modules and it works now.